# Platform location permission error with Flutter isolates

Tags: android, flutter, dart, location, dart-isolates

I'm attempting to run location updates on a Flutter isolate thread, the error is only present when running an isolate. Location requests works without issues on the main thread. The goal here is to run this as a background service, working with dart code only.
I am using [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin for location requests.

This is the error I am facing when starting the isolate:

> Exception has occurred. FlutterError
>   (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the
>   binding was initialized.

I have tried to include the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before runApp but without results.
Looking at the call stack of the error, it seems problems occur at the android location platform call: `checkPermissionStatus`
This happens regardless of what location plugin I am using, it stops at the permission status check.

I have figured it could have something to do with awaiting location permission user input, but this check will fail on a non-ui thread?

See this simple main.dart file for an example:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Isolate location test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Isolate location test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Isolate isolate;
  bool isRunning = false;
  String output = '';
  ReceivePort receivePort;

  void start() async {
    receivePort = ReceivePort();
    await Isolate.spawn(locationUpdate, receivePort.sendPort);
    receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
      setState(() {
        isRunning = true;
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      print("done");
    });
  }

  void stop() {
    if (isolate != null) {
      setState(() {
        isRunning = false;
      });
      receivePort.close();
      isolate.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate);
      isolate = null;
    }
  }

  static void locationUpdate(SendPort sendPort) async {
    Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus().then((status) {
      sendPort.send(status);
    });
    // Geolocator().getCurrentPosition().then((pos) {
    //   sendPort.send(pos);
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text(output)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: isRunning ? stop : start,
        child: Icon(isRunning ? Icons.stop : Icons.play_circle_filled),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've used `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before `runApp`. I don't know about `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`. I don't know if this is related to your issue. I know Flutter plugins and isolates were not a possible combination not long ago. I don't know how good that functionality is now.

Comment: @Ted Henry: my mistake, I meant `WidgetsFlutterBinding`, copied wrong text from the error. Well that's good insight, I don't actually have big hopes to get this working with only Flutter code.

Comment: Are you thinking to write the geolocation code in native Kotlin and Swift code in separate threads and then send results to the Dart code using an `EventChannel`?

Comment: If I need to go with native code, my case would probably look like: from Dart, start a separate native background service with the geolocation logic (which saves location data to local storage or similar), then with Dart code using a call to stop the service and retrieve the location results. I assume I only need a MethodChannel here

Comment: That's seems like a reasonable way to start if you need to go with native code.

Answer (score 0):

For the error that you're getting, a common solution for this issue is by calling `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before `runApp()` on `main()`.

With regards to the issue with isolate thread, there was a limitation on calling Platform channels from isolates as mentioned on this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45491). An [update on 2022](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937) has been posted that this feature should have been rolled out on the master channel.